# Flutter : RawKeyboard listener is not removing

Tags: android, flutter

I am using `RawKeyboard.instance.addListener(keyboardListener);` to listen to keypress events in flutter app.

When I go back to previous page and come back again, It adds another listener and it executes the code twice (it will keep adding new listener every time we come back to this page)

To avoid this behaviour I added `RawKeyboard.instance.removeListener(keyboardListener);` before adding listener but this does not seems to help out.

```
void keyboardListener(event) {
    if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
        tempString += event.character.toString();
        print('tempString: ${tempString}');
    }
  }
```

Any way to **remove existing listeners from RawKeyboard.instance**

Comment: try to dispose your listener before leaving the page